# How do I get the length of each row of the char** in C?

Tags: c, split, substring, c-strings

For instance:

```
char* arr = "x    xxxx\n"
            "x xx\n"
            "x  xxx\n";
```

I try to get the length of each row. I try sizeof, strlen, none of them works.
I only can get the total size, like:

```
int size = 0;
while(*arr) {
  size++;
  arr++;
}
```

Right now, I only know the size of row of "arr". I'm trying to find the length of each row. I can find it if the whole thing has equal length for each row.
But what if they are different? How should I approach this one? Or does C allow to do such things?
I was trying to think of malloc, realloc, but not sure that would work for this one. Please give me some hints.
Thank you.

Comment: "I try sizeof, strlen, none of them works." We don't see what you try, we can't tell if you try right or not.  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: That's a `char*` not a `char**` as - without commas - the three strings are concatenated into a single string.

Comment: @Dipstick
I see. So it a long string, and they "got separate" by '\n', so how could I get each length, like consider '\n' as a comma?

Comment: @pmg I see how it goes. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this (remember to `#include <string.h>`)

```
while (*arr) {
    size_t len = strcspn(arr, "\n");

    // use len and arr per your requirements
    work_with_data(arr, len);

    arr += len; // advance to the '\n' (or '\0')
    if (*arr) arr++; // if there really was an '\n' skip it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The string defined in the question is not a `char **`, it is a single C string with embedded newlines.

You can compute the lengths of the lines it contains with a simple iteration:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char arr[] = "x    xxxx\n"  // length 9
                 "x xx\n"       // length 4
                 "\n"           // length 0
                 "x  xxx\n";    // length 6
    size_t i, start, line = 1;

    for (i = start = 0; arr[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == '\n') {
            printf("The length of line %zu is %zu.\n", line, i - start);
            start = i + 1;
            line++;
        }
    }
    /* special case if the last line does not end with a newline */
    if (i > start) {
        printf("The length of line %zu is %zu.\n", line, i - start);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can simplify the loop using `strchr()` or `strcspn()`, which accepts a string of separators:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char arr[] = "x    xxxx\n"  // length 9
                 "x xx\n"       // length 4
                 "\n"           // length 0
                 "x  xxx\n";    // length 6
    char *p, *start;
    size_t line = 1;

    for (start = arr; (p = strchr(start, '\n')) != NULL; start = p + 1) {
        printf("The length of line %zu is %td.\n", line, p - start);
        line++;
    }
    /* special case if the last line does not end with a newline */
    if (*start) {
        printf("The length of line %zu is %zu.\n", line, strlen(start));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using `strcspn()` allows for the special case to be folded into the main loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char arr[] = "x    xxxx\n"  // length 9
                 "x xx\n"       // length 4
                 "\n"           // length 0
                 "x  xxx\n";    // length 6
    char *p = arr;
    size_t line = 1;

    while (*p != '\0') {
        size_t len = strcspn(p, "\n");
        printf("The length of line %zu is %zu.\n", line, len);
        line++;
        p += len + (p[len] != '\0');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) to find the newline characters in the string, and use that information for calculating the length of the individual lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char *arr = "x    xxxx\n"
                "x xx\n"
                "x  xxx\n";

    char *p = arr;

    for ( int i = 1; ; i++ )
    {
        char *q;

        q = strchr( p, '\n' );

        if ( q != NULL )
        {
            printf( "The length of line %d is %td.\n", i, q-p );
            p = q + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            size_t len = strlen( p );

            if ( len != 0 )
            {
                printf( "The length of line %d is %zu.\n", i, len );
            }

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
The length of line 1 is 9.
The length of line 2 is 4.
The length of line 3 is 6.
```

Comment: It is also worth noting that `strtok` is neither thread safe nor re-entrant, there is almost never a good reason to use `strtok` when there are alternatives such as `strchr` and `strcspn`

Comment: @DavidRanieri: In cases in which that is an issue, you can use platform-specific alternatives, such as [`strtok_r`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok_r.3.html) on POSIX. In the Microsoft C run-time library, `strtok` is thread-safe.

Comment: yes, and [strsep](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html) in unixes ... that's why I say it's worth mentioning this point.

Comment: `strtok` modifies the argument string, furthermore it will consider any sequence of newlines as a single separator... 2 more compelling reasons to dismiss this approach.

Comment: @chqrlie: Yes, you are correct that when using `strtok`, empty lines are not being counted. That is a serious problem. Also, requiring the string to be writable is also a serious issue. I have therefore modified my program to use `strchr` instead of `strtok`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: safer choice indeed. `strcspn` is more flexible (it handles multiple separators if needed) and allows for a simpler loop.

Comment: @chqrlie: Yes, you are right that `strcspn` is simpler. However, since it searches for more than one character, it is probably also slower than `strchr`. On the other hand, if `strchr` fails due to the last line not having a `\n`, then I must traverse the entire line again using `strlen`, which also hurts performance. This is not necessary when using `strcspn`.

Answer (score 0):

Each "row" of your string literal ends with the new line character `'\n'`.

```
char* arr = "x    xxxx\n"
            "x xx\n"
            "x  xxx\n";
```

So to determine the length of a row what you need is to find the position of the new line character. That can be done using the standard string function `strchr`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char* arr = "x    xxxx\n"
                "x xx\n"
                "x  xxx\n";    

    for ( const char *start = arr; *start; )
    {
        const char *end = strchr( start, '\n' );

        if ( end  == NULL )
        {
            end = start +strlen( start );
        }

        printf( "The row \"%.*s\" has the length %td\n",
                ( int )( end - start ), start, end- start );

        start = *end ? end + 1 : end;                
    }                
}
```

The program output is

```
The row "x    xxxx" has the length 9
The row "x xx" has the length 4
The row "x  xxx" has the length 6
```

The program output of the length of a row does not take into account the new line character. If you need to count it just increase the value of the length.